# int function parameter not working properly

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make something in C++ and I have a problem. I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//---MAIN---
using namespace std;
int af1 = 1;
int af2 = 1;

void lettersort(int cnt1) {
    cout << "RESULT:" << cnt1 << endl;
    cnt1++;
    cout << "RESULT WHEN+:" << cnt1 << endl;
    cout << "RESULT IN GLOBAL INT:" << af2 << endl;
}

int main()
{
    lettersort(af2);
    return 0;
}
```

So is there any way so that `cnt1++` affects `af2` too, to make it bigger ? I don't want to use `af2++` directly because I want to sometimes use `af1`.

Comment: That's not called "a void", it's called a *function*. "void" is a type.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment you are just passing `af2` to `cnt1` *by value*, so any changes to `cnt1` are strictly local to the function `lettersort`. In order to get the behaviour you want you need to pass your `cnt1` parameter *by reference*. Change:

```
void lettersort(int cnt1)
```

to:

```
void lettersort(int &cnt1)
```

Comment: Omg THANS SO MUTCH, i didnt know it is so simple. TNX :)

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the argument **by value**. I.e., you are copying the value of `af1` to a local variable in `lettersort`. This integer is then incremented, and disposed of when the function ends, without affecting the original `af1`. If you want the function to be able to affect `af1`, you should pass the argument **by reference**:

```
void lettersort(int& cnt1) { // Note the "&"
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understood your question:

there are 2 ways you can do that.

1. make **lettersort** function return the new value, and put it in af2

   ```
   int lettersort(int cnt1) {
       cout << "RESULT:" << cnt1 << endl;
       cnt1++;
       cout << "RESULT WHEN+:" << cnt1 << endl;
       cout << "RESULT IN GLOBAL INT:" << af2 << endl;
       return cnt1;
   }
   int main()
   {
   af2 = lettersort(af2);
   return 0;
   }
   ```
2. pass the value by reference. you can read about it [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/), but generally its about passing a pointer to that value. meaning whatever you do on the argument you are passing, will happen on the original var.

example:

```
    void foo(int &y) // y is now a reference
    {
        using namespace std;
        cout << "y = " << y << endl;
        y = 6;
        cout << "y = " << y << endl;
    } // y is destroyed here

    int main()
    {
        int x = 5;
        cout << "x = " << x << endl;
        foo(x);
        cout << "x = " << x << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

- here you have to just modified the argument pass to lettersort
  function   as passed by reference.
- for example if you declare and initialize any variable like:

  ```
    int a=10;    int &b = a;
  ```
- now a and b refer to the same value.if you change a then the changes
  also reflect in b also.
- so,

  ```
    cout << a; cout << b;
  ```
- both statement produce the same result across the program. so using
  this concept i modified the function argument and    made it as by
  reference.
- your correct code is :

  ```
    #include <iostream>


    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    int af1 = 1;
    int af2 = 1;
    void lettersort(int &cnt1) {
    cout << "RESULT:" << cnt1 << endl;
    cnt1++;
    cout << "RESULT WHEN+:" << cnt1 << endl;
    cout << "RESULT IN GLOBAL INT:" << af2 << endl;
    }

    int main()
    {
    lettersort(af2);
    return 0;
    }
  ```